# ReactiveForm for dynamically updated form entries

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

How to check status of myform in component to check if all the fields are filled or not?

HTML:

```
<div  [formGroup]="myform">
  <div *ngFor="let question of questions">
      <label>{{question.question}}</label>
                <select required >
                  <option selected disabled="disabled">Option</option>
                   <option *ngFor="let option of question['options']">{{option}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Question JSON coming from API:

```
 this.questions =  [
        {
          question: 'What is your age?',
          options: ['20', '30', '40']
        },

        {
          question: 'How much quantity?',
          options: ['1','2','3']
        }]
```

Comment: You're probably going to want to start here: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: @Brandon rather here : https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: And giving the dynamic side of the form, I would also suggest this : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: How do I instantiate the formgroup for the array of select boxes?

Comment: See the thing is that i want the form's status changes to check if it is valid and then update a boolean value.
this.myform.statusChanges
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .startWith(this.myform.status)
      .subscribe((status: string) => if(status=="Valid") {!booleanValue});
  }
But i think my form is not instantiated properly so my code never goes inside the statuschange

Comment: Of course your form isn't instanciated, your selects don't have a `formControlName` attribute.

Comment: @trichetriche can you help with that

Comment: I already gave you a link about reactive forms, and I frankly don't want to make a course to you right now ... Go ahead and read the link I gave you, and if you have trouble during your reading, make a question and refer me to it !

Comment: Sure @trichetriche. I went through the links and i created dynamic formControlName with the index. But there is only one part that iam stuck with. Instantiating myform, I tried it like this
this.myform == new FormGroup({}); But inside the formgroup how do i add the formarray for the select boxes

Comment: You have to make a `QuestionBase` [as explained here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#question-model). Once you have done that, you will be able to create a form group with `QuestionControlService`, as explained right under the first link I gave you in this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ReactiveForm, you need use a FormArray
A FormArray can be of FormControl or a FormGroup

FormArray of FormControls

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
    //We create an array of FormControl, each question a FormControl
    let data:FormControl[]=this.questions.map(q=>new FormControl());

    this.myform=this.fb.group({
      questions:new FormArray(data)
    })
}
//the .html
<!--we use *ngIf to show the form only when we create the form-->
<div *ngIf="myform"  [formGroup]="myform">
  <!--we iterate to myForm.get('questions').controls -->
  <!--we use our variable "questions" to show the label and options-->
  <div *ngFor="let question of myform.get('questions').controls;let i=index">
      <label>{{questions[i].question}}</label>
      <select required [formControl]="question" >
         <option value="null" disabled="disabled">Option</option>
         <option *ngFor="let option of questions[i].options">{{option}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
<!--just for check-->
{{myform?.value |json}}
```

If we use an array of formGroup we change some things

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
    //we create and array of FormGroup
    let data2:FormGroup[]=this.questions.map(q=>this.fb.group({
      option:null
    }));

    this.myform2=this.fb.group({
      questions:new FormArray(data2)
    })
}
<div *ngIf="myform2"  [formGroup]="myform2">
  <!--see that we say to Angular the "formArrayName" -->
  <div formArrayName="questions">
    <div *ngFor="let question of myform2.get('questions').controls;
        let i=index" [formGroupName]="i"> <!--don't forget formGroupName-->
        <label>{{questions[i].question}}</label>
        <!--the select use formControlName, our array is an array of FormGroup-->
        <select required formControlName="option" >
           <option value="null" disabled="disabled">Option</option>
           <option *ngFor="let option of questions[i].options">{{option}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  {{myform2?.value |json}}
```

Aclaration:@FrontEndDeveloper. One thing is the array question that we use to make the questions.(Perhafs I must be choose other names to the variables), other thing is the value of the form. The value of myform1={questions:["20","1"]}, the value of myform2={questions:[{option:"20"},{option:"2"}]}.

When we create an array of FormControl (or an array of FbGroup) I used map, equally I can do some like

```
let data:FormControl[]=[];
data.push(new FormControl());
data.push(new FormControl());
```

or

```
let data2:FormGroup[]=[];
data2.push(this.fb.group({
          option:null
        }));
data2.push(this.fb.group({
          option:null
        }));
```

Generally we have some data to initialize the form. (an object with some data) that we get from a dbs

```
//Imagine we have mydata{name:"A",options=["20","1"]}
//we can map this data to create the form
let data:FormControl[]=this.mydata.options.map(q=>new FormControl(q));
//or
   let data2:FormGroup[]=this.mydata.options.map(q=>this.fb.group({
          option:q
        }));

//Imagine we have mydata{name:"A",options=[{option:"20"},{option:"1"}]}
//we can map this data to create the form
let data:FormControl[]=this.mydata.options.map(q=>new FormControl(q.option));
//or
   let data2:FormGroup[]=this.mydata.options.map(q=>this.fb.group({
          option:q.option
        }));
```

Comment: @FrontEndDeveloper, I extended my answer, to make more clear the concept.About your question, If your questions are Observable of, you must subscribe the observable, and create the form In the function subscribe, not in ngInit

Comment: write console.log(questions), to see that you're receiving

Answer (score -1):

This would help you to understand reactive form basic functionalities.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/objects-equality-check-edhyk5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

It will help to understand:
1. FormBulder,
2. FormGroup,
3. Form Value changes etc.

Comment: Hi please follow the link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/objects-equality-check-reactive-forms?file=src/main.ts