# Just need JSON value without its key in nested FormArray - Angular

Tags: json, angular, angular5, angular6

I have an Angular form which gets input from a user and converts it into a JSON object.

I need an output like this:

```
{"Name":"sam","age":"21","Friends":[{"Name":"bob","mobile":["123","456","789"]}]}
```

I need the JSON values without the key, inside another JSON list

```
"mobile":["123","456","789"]
```

I am using Reactive forms and created a nested FormArray, by doing so, I am able to get an output like this:

```
{"Name":"sam","age":"21","Friends":[{"Name":"bob","mobile":"123"}]}
```

But, how do I create another nested FormArray just with the values(without key) as mentioned above?

My component.ts

```
this.peopleList = this._fb.group({
  Name : '',
  age : '',
  Friends: this._fb.array([this.CreateFriendList()])
});

CreateFriendList(): FormGroup {
   return this._fb.group({
      Name: '',
      mobile : '',
   });
 }
```

Comment: why you need mobile":["123","456","789"]  ?

Comment: To have a list of mobile numbers

Comment: is it a format only ? Why your mobile no has 9 digit only ?

Comment: The 3 digit number is just an example, a placeholder instead of making it big

Comment: You can have an FormArray of FormGroups or a FormArray of FormControls. There are several diferences in the .html. You can see an example in my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136985/reactiveform-for-dynamically-updated-form-entries/51143288#51143288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of doing this way,

```
this.peopleList = this._fb.group({
  Name : '',
  age : '',
  Friends: this._fb.array([this.CreateFriendList()])
});

CreateFriendList(): FormGroup {
   return this._fb.group({
      Name: '',
      mobile : '',
   });
 }

   const mobileList = this.peopleList.get('Friends') as FormArray;

for (let i = 0; i < mobileLists.length; i++) {
   this.peopleList.value.Friends[i].mobile = this.peopleList.value.Friends[i].mobile.split(' ') ;
 }
```

This way, User can enter multiple mobile numbers with space separated and the split operation returns as an array.

```
"mobile":["123","456","789"]
```

I can get the output like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need modify your code like this

First if you want to create array inside formgroup

```
CreateFriendList(): FormGroup {
   return this._fb.group({
      Name: '',
      mobile : new FormArray(mobile),
   });
 }
```

Then you have to loop the mobile number like this and pass that to formarray.
It will create list of array

```
// mobile number
   mobile=[1231323123,14231323,1231434134];
   const mobile= this.mobile.map(c => new FormControl(c));
```

Html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="mobile" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.mobile.contols; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    {{mobile[i] }}
  </label>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I want to get the mobile number from the form as a user input. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First define the array

```
const mobileNumbers = [];
```

Then use nested loops to get the mobile numbers out of the original object. In my example it‘s named `list`.

```
// get each main element
list.forEach( element => { 

    // get the mobile number of each friend
    element.Friends.forEach( friend => { 
        mobileNumbers.push(friend.mobile);
    });    

});

// check the outcome 
console.log(mobileNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
CreateFriendList(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      Name: '',
      mobile: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }



getFriendsData() {
        return this.peopleList.get('Friends') as FormArray;
    }

  getFriendsNumber(): Array<any>{
    return this.getFriendsData().get('mobile').value
  }

  updateMobileNumber(){
    this.getFriendsNumber().push('122')
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, How do I include the user input here?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create `control`s for each mobile number instead of creating `group`

```
createFriendList(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
        name: '',
        mobile : this._fb.array(this.createFriendsMobileList()),
    });
  }

  createFriendsMobileList() {
    return [
      this._fb.control(''),
      this._fb.control(''),
      this._fb.control('')
    ];
  }
```

See this example that I created here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-control

Comment: Thank you!. It would be nice if you tell me how to get an input from a user and make the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    private loginForm: any;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name:      ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            age:       ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            friends:   [
                       this.formBuilder.group({
                            fName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
                            mobiles: [[], Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
                        }),
                        Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
                                            Validators.minLength(1)])
                     ]
        });
    }
```

I am not sure that it will help you or not. You can take an idea from the above code.